# how can update the name of the legends and tooltip in a scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have this chart. I need change the name "setosa" to "name1" and "versicolor" to "name2". 
I need to update in real time
I do not know how to do it from c3.js, if I do it with d3.js, then when applying a resize, the texts return to be as in the beginning.

[image]

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
      xs: {
          setosa: 'setosa_x',
          versicolor: 'versicolor_x',
      },
      // iris data from R
      columns: [
          ["setosa_x", 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1, 4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3.0, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7, 3.3],
          ["versicolor_x", 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2.0, 3.0, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9, 3.1, 3.0, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 2.8, 3.0, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 2.7, 2.7, 3.0, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3.0, 2.5, 2.6, 3.0, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3.0, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5, 2.8],
          ["setosa", 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
          ["versicolor", 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.0, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.0, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3],
      ],
      type: 'scatter'
  },
  axis: {
      x: {
          label: 'Sepal.Width',
          tick: {
              fit: false
          }
      },
      y: {
          label: 'Petal.Width'
      }
  }
});

  /*
  setTimeout(function () {
      chart.load({
          xs: {
              virginica: 'virginica_x'
          },
          columns: [
              ["virginica_x", 3.3, 2.7, 3.0, 2.9, 3.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3.0, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3.0, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3.0, 2.8, 3.0, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 2.6, 3.0, 3.4, 3.1, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.4, 3.0],
              ["virginica", 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8, 2.5, 2.0, 1.9, 2.1, 2.0, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.0, 2.0, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2.0, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3, 1.8],
          ]
      });
  }, 4000);*/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hbajjjcv/

Comment: everywhere it says setosa make it say name1, repeat this process with versicolor and name2

Comment: @IrkenInvader I need to update in real time

Comment: I'm not sure what entirely you need to have happen here: try `d3.select('.c3-legend-item').select('text').text('name1')`

Comment: @RyanMorton not works, because when the chart is resized, the text es changed...

Comment: @yavg, well, what's suppose to happen?  Do you want a custom legend? http://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html

Comment: @RyanMorton look please https://i.imgur.com/Xdzl0nU.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can modify things after they get rendered, resized, or whatever on an interval.  C3 will always control the initial render and update so you may want to set the interval to 0:

```
setInterval(function(){
  d3.select('.c3-legend-item').select('text').text('name1');
  d3.select('.c3-tooltip-container').select('.c3-tooltip-name--setosa').select('.name').text('name1');      
}, 3000)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L4xpstc4/

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but it is not a good solution. I would be calling something all the time, and I would be modifying the texts all the time. I know that apparently it would solve the problem but it is not a good practice. in my real project the resize is allowed, that's why I'm looking for a way to achieve it from c3.js

Comment: Then you'll need to bring it up with the developers as they assume (rightly) that the column name is the correct column name.